# Using partial results from a query to calculate other rows of the same query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I have a hierarchical structure that comes from a list of project tasks and subtasks.  Subtasks can have also subtasks.

A task `prwbssequence` is its sequence number and a task `wbs_parseq` is the same as its parent `prwbssequence`.

All this information is on a Oracle table (`prtask`). Tasks that do not have subtasks (leafs) have `pristask` value = 0, and those that have (parent) have `pristask = 1`. I need to calculate the percent effort of all parent tasks.  This is the sum of the percent effort for its substask.

Bellow is the query I´d like to work (but doesn´t).  The subquery has sum(total_effort) and this is actually the result of the subquery.  What I would like this to do is calculate the total_effort for a parent task and then use this value to calculate it´s parent effort. Any idea on how to do this?

```
SELECT task.prprojectid, task.prname, task.pristask, 
DECODE (task.pristask, 
          1, task.percent_effort,
        0, (SELECT sum(total_effort)
              FROM prtask t2,
              WHERE prprojectid = task.prprojectid and task.pristask = 0 AND wbs_parseq =                   prwbssequence
              GROUP BY wbs_parseq)
        ) total_effort
FROM prtask task
AND task.prprojectid = 5008045
ORDER BY task.prwbssequence desc
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data structure for guidance? And plus create a SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com with it?

Comment: Are you trying to recursively sum the total_effort of each subtask for a given projectid?